# How to change enemy's colour when it spawns? Unity2d

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, colors

When I try to put ChangeColor() function in Spawn() or in Coroutine, enemies stop spawning.
I made an array of a few colours in unity, one of those should be randomly picked up and enemy's colour should be changed on that colour. There are no errors in compiler, what should I dо?

My code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class randomSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rndNum = 0f;
    public GameObject prefab;

    public Color[] color;
    public Renderer render;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine("count");
        
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        rndNum = Random.Range(-10f, 10f);
        
    }
    void Spawn()
    {
        
        Instantiate(prefab, new Vector2(rndNum, 6f), Quaternion.identity);
        
    }

    IEnumerator count()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            
            
            Spawn();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.2f);
        }
        
    }

    void ChangeColor()
    {
        render.material.color = color[Random.Range(1, color.Length - 1)];
    }
}
```

Comment: well you never call changecolor .. so how do you expect it to know?

Comment: It has been a while but I think you need to get the object from Instantiate(prefab, new Vector2(rndNum, 6f), Quaternion.identity); and then change the Material color of that object

Comment: Sidenote: it should be `Random.Range(1, color.Length)` as the second parameter for the `int` overload is **exclusive**

Answer (score 0):

In spawn you should take Renderer of your newly created object and set color there.

```
void Spawn()
{        
    var newNpc = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector2(rndNum, 6f), Quaternion.identity);
    var renderer = newNpc.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    renderer.material.color = color[Random.Range(0, color.Length)];
    
}
```

Or add new script onto your prefab and put that code into Start function there

```
public Color[] color;

void Start()
{
    var renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    renderer.material.color = color[Random.Range(0, color.Length)];
}
```